# How do i declare the Encryptable Property Source annotation from Jasypt for the application yaml outside of a jar file?

Tags: jar, properties, annotations, jasypt

My code works if my application.yaml is inside my resource folder.

```
    @EncryptablePropertySource("application.yaml")
public class Application {     public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

But for my client it is needed the application.yaml is outside of the jar (in the same path of the .jar file)

if i try `@EncryptablePropertySource("path:..\\application.yaml")` or `("path:C\\users\\me\\application.yaml")` it doesn't seem to work. same counts if i use ("file:application.yaml")

Any sugestions? thanks in advance

EDIT: it worked like this `@EncryptablePropertySource("file:\\\Users\me\application.yaml")

but i should have ("file:\\\..\application.yaml") or something like this because the client directory will be not the same as mine ofcourse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I did a workaround like this : let me know what you think.

mainclass:

```
@EncryptablePropertySource("file:\\\\\\${position}")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

application.yaml:

```
position:  Users\me\application.yaml
```